# cfdump alternative to pass output as a string

Tags: coldfusion

I'd like to store the output of the cfdump as a string temporarily. I know there's a way to store it in a file, but is there a way that I can get the equivalent of `cfdump format='text'`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Would using cfsavecontent work for you?

```
<cfsavecontent variable="theDump">
    <cfdump var="#cgi#" expand="yes" format="text">
</cfsavecontent>

<cfoutput>
    #theDump#
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 1):

shaunw has the right idea. For bonus modularity, roll that into your own custom tag or component function so you can reuse it throughout your applications